# Count up values in Chart JS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

how do I make the values in Chart JS update as the bar progresses?

For example, I want the values for each bar to start at 0 and count up to there value, stopping when the bar has reached it's height.

At the moment, it just displays it's full value upon animation start (when the page loads)

Chart JS docs:
https://www.chartjs.org/

Here is a plugin I found:
https://emn178.github.io/chartjs-plugin-labels/samples/demo/

Here is a JS Fiddle (ignore the shaking!)
https://jsfiddle.net/8uehq5xr/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Horizontal Bar Chart</title>
<script src="../../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.7.3/dist/Chart.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/emn178/chartjs-plugin- 
labels/src/chartjs-plugin-labels.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="bar-chart" width="800" height="450"></canvas>

<div id="value">100</div>

<Script>


// Bar chart
new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart"), {
type: 'bar',
data: {
  labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"],

  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Population (millions)",
      backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
      data: [2478,5267,734,784,433]
    }
  ]
},



options: 
{
    plugins: {
        labels: 
        {
            render: 'value',

            fontSize: 20,
        }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: false
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: false
      }],
    },
    tooltips: { enabled: true},
    hover: {animationDuration: 1},

}
});

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try to draw the chart with ajax. try to redraw the chart after ajax callbacks

Answer (score 1):

I assume you would like something like a fast counter synchronized with chart drawing, can't you do it with just a for loop refreshing data given to chart.js until you reach their real value ?

No need for a plugin if it's a that small improvement you need

**Example:**

final data is [2478,5267,734,784,433]
initial data is [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

1°) set an interval incrementing data of 1/10 of their value by example, each 200ms

-> after 200ms you now have [247, 526, 73, 78, 43]

2°) cancel interval once you reached final data

You can then play with interval and increment steps (1/100 in stead of 1/10 by example)

Here is a workaround (but I bet you block with chart drawing ?)

```
const currentData = [0,0,0,0,0];
const finalData = [2478,5267,734,784,433];
const stepTick = 0.1;
let stepNumber = 1;

const redrawingAfter1Step = setInterval(() => {
    for(let i = 0; i < currentData.length; i++) {
    currentData[i] = stepTick * stepNumber * finalData[i];
  }

  drawChart(currentData);

  if ((stepNumber * stepTick) === 1) {
    clearInterval(redrawingAfter1Step);
  }

  stepNumber++;

}, 500);
```

Comment: Yes, that was my thought - but I don't know how to do that in the code

Comment: I've added a JS Fiddle in the OP above. Try adding it there.